# How to execute a query with multiple select option choices using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like my PHP query to update dynamically the data displayed without a refresh.

I have these two select option choices.

```
<select name="d">
<option <?php if ( $d == '50' ) { echo 'value="50" selected="selected" >50 km '; } else { echo 'value="50" >50 km '; } ?></option>
<option <?php if ( $d == '100' ) { echo 'value="100" selected="selected" >100 km '; } else { echo 'value="100" >100 km '; } ?></option>
</select>

<select name="o">
<option <?php if ( $o == '1' ) { echo 'value="1" selected="selected" >from nearest to furthest '; } 
else { echo 'value="1" >from nearest to furthest '; } ?>
</option>
<option <?php if ( $o == '2' ) { echo 'value="2" selected="selected" >from furthest to nearest '; } 
else { echo 'value="2" >from furthest to nearest '; } ?>
</option>
</select>
```

Here is the PHP part with the 3 variables `a` (from a text input), `d` and `o`.

```
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : '';
$d = isset($_GET['d']) ? $_GET['d'] : ''; 
$o = isset($_GET['o']) ? $_GET['o'] : '';

if ( !empty($_GET['a']) )
{

$request = mysqli_query($sql,"
SELECT * 
FROM adresses 
WHERE adress = '".$a."' HAVING distance <= ".$d." order by ".$o."");            

}
```

Here is the final result :

```
echo '<div id="result">';

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($request) )

{

echo '<p>'.$row['shop'].' | '.$row['adress'].' | '.echo $row['town'].'</p>';

}

echo '</div>';
```

I've never used AJAX before and I would like to know how to run a query like this one above.

Here is my attempt for the AJAX part (not sure about the syntax) :

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#result").change(function(){
      var a = $(this).val();
      var d = $(this).val();
      var o = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        data: { a: $a, d: $d, o: $o } ,
        success: function(result){
        $("#result").html(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please, could you tell me what am I supposed to put in the `test.php` file ?

Comment: What do you want `test.php` to do? It looks like you have the logic in your second code block (though I would add some validation to the data coming in) and what is currently happening?

Comment: I want to execute the SQL query with the new value from the select option. Does it mean that I just have to copy / paste the `$request` in the PHP file ?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In test.php you should gather data from the server, ie, MySQL.

```
    $a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : '';
    $d = isset($_GET['d']) ? $_GET['d'] : ''; 
    $o = isset($_GET['o']) ? $_GET['o'] : '';

    if ( !empty($_GET['a']) )
    {

    $request = mysqli_query($sql,"
    SELECT * 
    FROM adresses 
    WHERE adress = '".$a."' HAVING distance <= ".$d." order by ".$o."");            

    }

echo '<div id="result">';

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($request) )

{

echo '<p>'.$row['shop'].' | '.$row['adress'].' | '.echo $row['town'].'</p>';

}

echo '</div>';
```

Whatever php script returns (echo in case above) it will be in your result variable here:

```
success: function(result){
$("#result").html(result);
}
```

Few more things.

You are defining variables incorrectly, it should be:

```
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var d = $('#d').val();
  var o = $('#o').val();
```

For this to work you need to assign id to your select's

```
<select name="d" id="d">
```

JS variable don't have $ sign, so the variable you sending to test.php should be:

```
data: { a: a, d: d, o: o }
```

Note: None of above is tested, just copy/paste of your code to get you on the right track.